# What will always call earlier: servletContextListener method or constructor?

Tags: java, jax-ws, servletcontextlistener

Here is the code:

```
@WebService(...)
public class service implements someInterface, ServletContextListener
{
    public service()
    {
        // action1
    }

    public void contextInitialized(...)
    {
        // action2
    }
}
```

Q: What action will be always first?

Comment: `System.out.println("<method name here> was called!");` any reason why you don't just find out?

Comment: And please follow the CamelCasingConventions for class and method names. Otherwise you just increase the confusion.

Comment: I asked about principle of working ServletContextListener methods. System.out... would give me only private result.

Comment: @slider what you say doesn't make sense, since `ServletContextListener` merely describes methods which you're contracting to provide; you have full control to sprinkle that output (or any other that's appropriate for your environment) in all of your methods.

Comment: -1. As mah points out, basic debugging would answer this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `contextInitialized` is a method that belongs to [a specific instance of a class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). In order to get hold of such an instance, [a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) of the class `service` must be invoked first. Therefore, the constructor will be called first. Anything else is not technically possible in Java.

One additional remark: It is a Java convention to spell classes with a capital first letter. You should stick to this convention in order to make your code better readable.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thought that it can have some specific.

Comment: Hypothetically, there are possibilities to create an instance of a class **without** calling any constructor. This is however a JVM hack which is meant to be only used internally, for example to provide deserialization. Normally, you will never encounter such a construction of an object. Providing a default constructor to a framework for creating an instance before calling its life cycle methods is quite common on the other side.